# Configure huawei e3372 4g dongle with Singtel Hi card 3g data on Ubuntu 18.04/Jetson nano project

Tags: networking, network-manager, usb-modem, 4g

I am trying to get the huawei 4g Dongle to work on my jetson nano in order to provide network for me.
 NVIDIA Jetson TX1
 L4T 32.3.1 [ JetPack 4.3 ]
 Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
 Kernel Version: 4.9.140-tegra
 CUDA 10.0.326
this is my L4T and kernel version.
Firstly, clone the BuildKernelAndModules in the Jetsonhacks Nano repository in github, https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/buildKernelAndModules

git clone https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/buildKernelAndModules

Open the folder where it is downloaded, it should be in your home directory.
Once you located your buildKernelAndModules folder, run the following codes
    1. ./getKernelSources.sh
    2. ./makeKernel.sh
    3. ./makeModules.sh
    4. ./copyImage.sh
These steps will take awhile(especially the makeKernel and makeModules scripts)
Once everything is downloaded, run the ./editConfig.sh

In the config settings,

Enable these following settings :
Device Drivers --->
 [*] Network device support --->
   [*] PPP (point-to-point protocol) support -- PPP
     [M] PPP BSD-Compress compression -- PPP_BSDCOMP
     [M] PPP Deflate compression -- PPP_DEFLATE
     [M] PPP MPPE compression (encryption) -- PPP_MPPE
     [M] PPP over Ethernet - PPPOE
     [*] PPP support for async serial ports -- PPP_ASYNC
     [M] PPP support for sync tty ports -- PPP_SYNC_TTY
 [*] USB support --->
   <*> USB Serial Converter support --->
     [*] USB Serial Console device support -- USB_SERIAL_CONSOLE
     [*] USB Generic Serial Driver -- USB_SERIAL_GENERIC
     [*] USB driver for GSM and CDMA modems -- USB_SERIAL_OPTION
The * means it is built as a kernel, the M denotes it is built as a Module.

To enable these in the config file, type ‘y’ to enable it as a kernel, ‘m’ to enable it as a module.

Once this is done, save and exit the file.

Run ./makeKernel.sh and ./makeModules.sh to build the new kernels.
Run ./copyImage.sh to copy the image to the boot folder.
Reboot the jetson by:

### Sudo reboot now

I Could successfully enable the 4g dongle but need to configure the APN for the dongle.
Then i proceeded withInstall ModemManager and NetworkManager by running these 2 codes :
sudo apt-get install modemmanager
sudo apt-get install network-manager

Run lsusb to check if the dongle is connected
You should see this : 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies

Once you confirmed that the dongle is connected, run mmcli -L to see if it is detected as a modem.If they mentioned “modemmanager process in the bus unavailable”, you have to enable ModemManager as a service and start it on boot:

sudo systemctl enable ModemManager
sudo systemctl start ModemManager

Run mmcli -L again and you should have detected a modem with a number at the end.

Run mmcli -L x (replace x with the number of the modem)
This will show you the full modem settings.

Check whether the dongle is configured and to confirm whether the device is
detected:
nmcli d

Next type this in the Terminal : 
nmcli c add type gsm ifname ttyUSB0 con-name sandbox_lte apn
e-ideas ipv4.dns “8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4”
i am using e-ideas because this is from singtel
Then i Type these into the Terminal:

nmcli c edit sandbox_lte
goto ipv4
set dns 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
verify
save

### Activate

But after i run nmcli d

ttyUSB0  gsm       connecting (prepare)  sandbox_lte

It shows it was still connecting and the internet logo on right hand top was forever connecting.

If anyone happens to know please help!
thanks